# What's the correct order of the words "option" and "-d"?

Tags: word-order

I asked a technical question on another StackExchange website, and the title of the question is:

> What does the option "-d" of the ... command do?

Someone helped me improve it like this:

> What does the "-d" option of the ... command do?

Does the improved version sound more natural?
In case you are interested, here is [the link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701738/what-does-the-d-option-of-the-read-shell-command-do-when-i-use-it-with-an-e) to the question.

Comment: You're asking about computer terminology, not English. I think this is off-topic here. You'd be better off asking the user that revised it why they did so.

Comment: It's not necessarily restricted to computer contexts. We can ask *What does **the "X" button** do?* or *"What does **[the] button "X"** do?* interchangeably, for example. And there are probably even more common examples of the same basic construction that I can't think of right now. Some people in some contexts might disagree over whether it's idiomatic to include / dispense with the definite article, but I'd say that's just a matter of stylistic choices.

Comment: Perhaps *Do you know Pat the Irishman?* and *Do you know the Irishman Pat?* Not that the *question* format is a relevant factor here.

Answer (score 3):

Both possibilities are found.

In *the option -d*, "-d" is treated almost like a name. like "The book *Gone with the Wind*"

In *the -d option*, "-d" is treated like a an attributive, like *the accounts book*.

Comment: There's *something* slightly different about OP's "options", as opposed to your "books". I think we *have* to include the definite article in *Have you got the book "Gone with the Wind"?* and *"Have you got the accounts book?*, but we don't need to include it in *Did you use [the] option "-d"?* Only non-native speakers would be likely to ask *Did you use "-d" option?* without an article, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right, it's complicated. I think that the whole of _option -D_ is optionally treated as a name. But that's not the whole answer, becuase _the_ is possible, just not required. It's not just the computer world - we find this in assembly instructions for furniture too: "Attach handle C to frame H".